# Labels in igraph python are plotted wrong

Tags: python, plot, label, igraph

Using igraph with python, I am trying to **plot labels both in vertices and edges**, but they are **displayed wrong**.

My code:

```py
import igraph as ig

g = ig.Graph(directed = True, n=4)
g.add_edges([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3)])
g.es["weight"]=[1,2,3]

g.es["label"] = ["blue", "green", "yellow"]
g.vs["label"] = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"]

ig.plot(g, layout = g.layout("rt"), edge_width = g.es['weight'])
```

I realized the first time I run the program, they are displayed fine:

[image]

But if I try to run it again with different labels:

```py
g.es["label"] = [1, 2, 3]
g.vs["label"] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

it fails:

[image]

It happens the same if instead I use the options `vertex_label` and `edge_label`:

```py
import igraph as ig

g = ig.Graph(directed = True, n=4)
g.add_edges([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3)])
g.es["weight"]=[1,2,3]

ig.plot(g, layout = g.layout("rt"), vertex_label=["a", "b", "c", "d"], edge_label = [1, 2, 3], edge_width = g.es['weight'])
```

But now if I close and open the program, and try to run first with

```py
g.es["label"] = [1, 2, 3]
g.vs["label"] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

it works fine:

[image]

But then if I try:

```py
g.es["label"] = ["blue", "green", "yellow"]
g.vs["label"] = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"]
```

it does not:

[image]

Maybe is a problem of my installation. I am running it on Visual Studio Code with python 3.8.3 64-bit and anaconda. I installed it with `pip install python-igraph` and with Cairo downloaded from [this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo) (as they explain in the [documentation of igraph for Windows](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/install.html#installing-igraph)), in particular the `pycairo-1.20.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` version.

**Any ideas how to solve it?**

Comment: This is unexpected. I run your code on Jupyter Notebook + `igraph 0.8.3`. No letters appears in vertex labels. How did you get these labels `l`, `A`, `i`, `c`? It should be assigned within a command `g.vs["label"] = [0, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @mathfux yes, it is quite strange. I updated now my post because I realized the labels are never plotted right.

Comment: @mathfux Actually now I found if I restart the program and rerun. The first time it plots properly the labels, but if I run it again, it does not. I am running it on Visual Studio Code with python 3.8.3 64-bit and anaconda. I installed it with `pip install python-igraph` and with Cairo downloaded from [this site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo) (as they explain in the [documentation of igraph for Windows](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/install.html#installing-igraph)), in particular the `pycairo-1.20.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` version.

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 + PyCharm or anaconda + jupyter notebook but never seen these issues. It seems that setting `g.vs["label"]` and `g.es.["label"]`  has some unexpected effect which you can report in `igraph discourse group`. Might `vertex_label` or `edge_label` attributes inside `ig.plot` will help you? Like `vertex_label=range(g.vcount())` or `vertex_label=g.vs["label"]`.  These Cairo surfaces are scarying me constantly.

Comment: It is exactly the same problem. :/

Comment: It's obviously a bug. Try to report it on [igraph discourse group](https://igraph.discourse.group) or [github](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues). They're responding more frequently and StackOverflow is quite passive about `igraph`

Comment: @mathfux Note that the GitHub issue tracker you linked is for the C library, while this issue concerns python-igraph. The question was posted [on the igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/labels-in-igraph-python-are-plotted-wrong/513/). Thanks for the directing OP there!